# If $P(A) = \frac{1}{3}, P(B) = \frac{1}{2}$, and $P(A \cup B) = \frac{3}{4}$ find...

Tags: probability, elementary-set-theory

**If $P(A) = \frac{1}{3}, P(B) = \frac{1}{2}$, and $P(A \cup B) = \frac{3}{4}$ Find:**

$P(A \cap B),\\  
P(A^\complement \cup B^\complement) \\
P(A^\complement \cap B)$

**Here is what I did:**

$P(A \cap B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cup B) = \frac{1}{12}$

$P(A^\complement \cup B^\complement) = P( [A \cap B]^\complement ) = 1 - \frac{1}{12} = \frac{11}{12}$ (Not sure if this is correct)

$P(A^\complement \cap B) = ...$ (I'm not quite sure how to approach this)

Comment: This is really a problem in set theory - how can you rewrite $A^\complement \cap B$ in terms of $A$, $B$, $A \cap B$ etc. As $A \cup A^\complement$ is the whole space, and the union is disjoint, you also have for every subset $B$: $B = (B \cap A) \cup (B \cap A^\complement)$ and the union is disjoint. This will lead you to Ahmad Bazzi's answer.

Comment: Try drawing a venn diagram with 2 circles, one for A and one for B.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ponder the following diagram, where $()$ denotes $A$ and $[]$ denotes $B$:

$$( *** [ * ) ***** ] ***$$

$A$ has four stars, out of twelve, i.e. $1/3$.

$B$ has six stars, out of twelve, i.e. $1/2$.

$A\cup B$ has nine stars, out of twelve, i.e. $3/4$.

You now have the complete Venn diagram, and can answer all the questions directly.  $B\cap A^c$ has five stars.

Answer (score 3):

All is correct. For the last one you'd need:

$$P(A^\complement \cap B) = P(B) - P(A \cap B) = \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{12} = \frac{5}{12}$$

**Image to help visualize stuff**

[image]

Comment: How did you arrive to $P(A^\complement \cap B)$ = $P(B) - P(A \cap B)$. Is this a general rule? Or something that should be intuitive?

Comment: @AznBoyStride Take a look at the image that i just added, can you see why ?

Comment: Yes makes perfect sense now!

Comment: Its just a rearrangement of the Law of Total Probability.  $\mathsf P(B)=\mathsf P(A\cap B)+\mathsf P(A^\complement\cap B)$